# Comparing string arrays

Tags: c#, asp.net, array

My code does what I need it to do, but I think I am missing the "right" way to do this with comparing the arrays. Essentially what I need this to do is compare a textbox entry against two different arrays and redirect based on which value matches.

```
Protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{              
      string[] str1 = new string[] {"87002", "87001", "87005"};
      string[] str2 = new string[] {"97002", "97003", "97004"};

      for (int i = 0; i < str1.Length; i++)
      {
          string comp1 = str1[i];
          if (comp1 == TextBox1.Text.ToString())
          {
              Response.Redirect("Page1.aspx");
          }
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < str2.Length; i++)
      {
          string comp2 = str2[i];
          if (comp2 == TextBox1.Text.ToString())
          {
              Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
          }
      }          
      Response.Redirect("Unknown.aspx");
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer `List<string>` to arrays, and use the [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) method instead of looping. Other than that... what *exactly* are you asking? Is there something wrong with your code?

Comment: I think OP may be looking for the Array.Exists method?

Comment: basically, what is the right way to compare two strings? nothing wrong with the code, I just feel uncomfortable with it.

Comment: Is the question "how to determine whether a string is in an array?" or "how to compare two strings?"

Comment: how to determine whether a string is in an array

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would do this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{              
    string[] str1 = new string[] {"87002", "87001", "87005"};
    string[] str2 = new string[] {"97002", "97003", "97004"};

    if (str1.Contains(TextBox1.Text))
        Response.Redirect("Page1.aspx");

    if (str2.Contains(TextBox1.Text))
        Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");

    Response.Redirect("Unknown.aspx");
}
```

You don't need the `ToString()` calls - `TextBox.Text` should already be a `string`.

Comment: I would do this, but also use arrays of `int` (assuming those values are not just for demonstration.) If `TextBox1.Text` does not parse as an `int`, you can go straight to Unknown.aspx without searching.

Answer (score 3):

Would you not be better using the array.Contains(..) method?
For example: str1.Contains(TextBox1.Text); should suffice to check whether the string is within the array.
It might be worth also storing the two string arrays as HashSet also for speed.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `HashSet`, but I don't understand "for speed if they're not *very* big".  The benefit of using `HashSet` will be *greater* for a larger set of values; that phrase seems to imply that `HashSet` would only be useful for a relatively small set of values.

Comment: I'm also unsure what I meant by that..removed it now.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that should work, however there is a cleaner way to write this using Linq. Now if you are not using 3.5+ then you will stick with your way.

Try below.

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] str1 = new string[] { "87002", "87001", "87005" },
                     str2 = new string[] { "97002", "97003", "97004" };

            string txt = txtBox1.Text.Trim();

            if (str1.Any(x => x.Equals(txt)))
                Response.Redirect("Page1.aspx");
            else if (str2.Any(x => x.Equals(txt)))
                Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
            else
                Response.Redirect("Unknown.aspx");
        }
```

Unfortunatly we cant avoid a loop here but what we have done is used the "ANY" method of the string array. The "any" method returns a boolean (true\false) if any of the values in the Collection matches your lambada expression. In this instance we are simply saying does x (the item in the collection) match the txt (from txtBox1).

If it does we can redirect to the correct location.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

How about using `Switch`

```
 switch(input)
 {
   case foo: do something;
         break;

    case bar: do something;
         break;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would have used a `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> redirects = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "87002", "Page1.aspx" },
    { "87001", "Page1.aspx" },
    { "87005", "Page1.aspx" },
    { "97002", "Page2.aspx" },
    { "97003", "Page2.aspx" },
    { "97004", "Page2.aspx" },
};

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{              
      if (redirects.ContainsKey(TextBox1.Text))
      {
          Response.Redirect(redirects[TextBox1.Text]);
      }
      else
      {     
          Response.Redirect("Unknown.aspx");
      }
}
```

This solution separates the data from the algorithm, which I think is a good idea.

Comment: This could be improved with `TryGetValue` so you only need to do the lookup once.